# Community Auth reset password

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I am using Community Auth library but I noticed there are no methods for reset password. May I know where to get the reset password method if any? Thank you.

Comment: you can check **Example_model.php** file for reset password function. funcitona name **recovery_password_change** and **_change_password**.